# mix: not found (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, npm

I have Homestead virtual machine and command like "npm run prod" works well there.

If it works at virtual machine then problem is in VPS I guess. But I can't understand what is wrong...

I have VPS also and it was working well but now it gives the next message (even after reinstalling OS):

> sh: 1: mix: not found

I tried next subsequence command:

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
npm clean-install
```

then

```
npm i --save-dev laravel-mix@latest && 
npm i --save-dev sass-loader@latest && 
npm i --save-dev postcss@latest && 
npm i --save-dev webpack@latest
```

There is my packages.json file:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.20",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.3.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4"
},
"dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.2.3",
    "svgo": "^2.3.1"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 come by default with laravel.mix so you dont need install it again.
only run `npm install` but if you need install the complete scaffolding
you need execute first `composer require laravel/ui` and then add the basic setup (execute one of them)

// Generate basic scaffolding...

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
  php artisan ui vue
  php artisan ui react
```

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

after this execute `npm install` and then `npm run dev`

Comment: I always left laravel mix in the dev dependencies as [laravel brings it by default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/59f33209d5afc2f9f1c6c3c38280ae9eb5b15aed/package.json#L14) and never had problems. What is your basis for saying that "Laravel mix should be installed by dependencies json not as devDependencies"?

Comment: This is Windows related problem. Why do you post artisan commands here? I really tired to see such stupid unrelated recipes